# Lost Source Sketch

Tags: arduino-mega

I wrote an interface to a radio about 1-year ago. I have since rebuilt that machine. Is there any way to retrieve the code. Now I do not expect it to be sources code.
I know the radio code still works as I tried it the other day. Part of the problem is that I am using about 30 wires all on the rear end of the card
and  have to figure out which pins that they go to in my radio. My interface has two DB25 connectors. And the decoder 2 of 5 negative going signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asusming the lock bits on the MCU haven't been set, you can use avrdude to download the contents of flash and EEPROM to your system. From there you can use avr-objdump to disassemble the .hex file and try to figure out how it works. I recommend looking at the disassembly of a .elf file from a current project as well as having both the avr-gcc and avr-libc documentation as well as the ATmegaXXX0 datasheet close at hand at all times.

Comment: Once you have the .hex file off the chip you can do this to diassemble it: `avr-objdump -j .sec1 -d -m avr3 myfile.hex`